# Responsive display: flex; depending on image orientation

Tags: html, css, flexbox, grid

Seems like something quite easy to be achieved, but I'm trying to figure out the simpliest way to do it.

I'm basically having two types of images on my page: portrait and landspace.

- I would like the landscapes picture to take full width of the parent div,
- and the portrait pictures to be 2 by row.

**& this dynamically, without having to invoke the `:nth-child` selector.**

[image]

```css
main{
  background: orange;
  width: 60vw;
}

section{
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;

}

img{
  flex: 1;
 /* width: 100%; */
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="" class="hero">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/320" alt="" class="hero">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/600/300" alt="" class="hero">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="" class="hero">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/700/300" alt="" class="hero">


  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you only want styling applied to the `section`-element? E.g. no `max-width: 50%` on the `img`-elements? If so, this is not possible with flex only.

Comment: To make sure, is it depending on orientation or width ? If the image is 3000x8000, should it have a second image next to it since it's a portrait ?

Comment: @Cédric the image is explaning it quite simply... if the next image is a portrait, then there is two portraits on the same row, if the next image is a landscape, the image goes in the next row

Comment: @SigurdMazanti well, it should be possible with grid though, right ?

Comment: This is doable with grid yes, but you will have to put the images in the exact order as your example image is showing (1st picture is landscape, 2nd & 3rd is portrait, 4th is  landscape). If you want the layout to be fully dynamic without applying the correct order in your markup, you will have to use JS like Seiteros' solution @Aurore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get aspect ratio using js and then apply styling based on it.

```js
const images = document.querySelectorAll('.hero')

images.forEach((image) => {
  image.addEventListener('load', function() {
    let width = image.offsetWidth;
    let height = image.offsetHeight;
    let ratio = width / height;

    if (ratio < 1) {
      image.classList.add('portrait')
    } else {
      image.classList.add('landscape')
    }
  });
})
```

```css
main {
  background: orange;
  width: 60vw;
}

section {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

.portrait {
  width:  50%;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="" class="hero">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/320" alt="" class="hero">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/600/300" alt="" class="hero">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="" class="hero">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/700/300" alt="" class="hero">


  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: yep, that's working indeed, but having js to achieve that is kind of a pain haha.
Thanks, will try to keep searching for a css only solution and mark it as accepted if I don't find any!